# Running time of 2 nearly programs in 1000 queens problem is quite different using simulated annealing algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm

About the problem, The goal is placing 1000 queens in a 1000x1000 chessboard  so each of them is not conflicted.
For the code below and the annealing algorithm ( I try to explain this :< ):

Firstly, I initialize the chessboard by a array of 1000 elements, each element present the column and the value of it present the row of a queen, then I shuffle it to reduce conflicts.
Secondly, for each move I choose randomly 2 columns if the number of conflicts after swapping reduce or the probility of e^(dif/T) is happened (dif is number of conflicts change if swap there 2 columns, T is reduced time by time - do this to avoid local extreme aka accept a worst case with hope  to find a better case), I swap there 2 columns and update new number of conflicts, repeat until I get the number of conflicts equal zero.

I have 2 programs, the first one runs completely in about 6s while the second one's time is about 32s with 140,000 swaps. I think there is no difference in time complexity i dont know the reason why:
The first program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

pair<vector<int>,int> data;
int n;
double T;

void init() { // Khoi tao
    cout << "Input n = ";
    cin >> n;
    T = n;
    srand(time(0));
    vector<int> a;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a.push_back(i);
    }
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int temp = rand() % a.size();
        data.first.push_back(a[temp]);
        a.erase(a.begin() + temp);
    }
    // Tinh H(n)
    int result = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < n - 1; i++) {
        for(int j = i + 1 ; j < n; j++){
            if(j - i == data.first[j] - data.first[i] || data.first[i] + i == data.first[j] + j){
                result++;
            }
        }
    }
    data.second = result;
}

pair<vector<int>,int> Next_move(pair<vector<int>,int> data, int i, int j) {
    pair<vector<int>,int> temp = data;
    int heuristic = data.second;
    int jj = data.first[i];
    int ii = data.first[j];
    temp.first[i] = ii;
    temp.first[j] = jj;
    int count1 = 0, count2 = 0;

    for (int k = 0; k < data.first.size(); k++) {
        if (k != i) {
            if (ii + i == temp.first[k] + k
                || ii - i == temp.first[k] - k) {
                count1++;
            }

            if (jj + i == data.first[k] + k
                || jj - i == data.first[k] - k) {
                count2++;
            }
        }
        if (k != j) {
            if (jj + j == temp.first[k] + k
                || jj - j == temp.first[k] - k) {
                count1++;
            }
            if (ii + j == data.first[k] + k
                || ii - j == data.first[k] - k) {
                count2++;
            }
        }
    }
    temp.second = (heuristic - count2 + count1);
    return temp;
}

void show(pair<vector<int>,int> data) {
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << data.first[i] << " ";
    }
    int conflicts = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++){
            if(abs(data.first[i] - data.first[j]) == j-i)
                conflicts ++;
        }
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Conflicts = " << conflicts << " ";
}

int steps = 0;

void solve() {
    srand(time(0));
    double p;
    while(T > 0) {
        steps++;
        if(data.second == 0){
            show(data);
            break;
        }
        T *= 0.99;
        int i = rand()%n;
        int j = rand()%n;
        pair<vector<int>, int> next_move = Next_move(data,i,j);
        if(next_move.second == 0) {
            cout << next_move.second << endl;
            cout << "Steps: " << steps << endl;
            cout << "Result: ";
            show(next_move);
            break;
        }
        int delta = next_move.second - data.second;
        if(delta < 0) {
            data = next_move;
            cout << next_move.second << endl;
        }
        else {
            p = exp(-delta/double(T));
            if(rand()/double(RAND_MAX) < p){
                data = next_move;
                cout << next_move.second << endl;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    clock_t start = clock();
    init();
    cout << "The first value of heuristic: " << data.second << endl;
    solve();
    clock_t  finish = clock();
    cout << endl << "Time running: " << finish - start << " micro seconds." << endl;
    cout << "Steps = " << steps << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The second one:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <limits.h>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

int N;
int step = 0;
// positions and heuristic
pair<vector<int>,int> data;

void init(){
    cout << "Input n: ";
    cin >> N;
    vector<int> v(N);
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        v[i] = i;
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        swap(v[i],v[abs(rand()%N)]);
    
    int obj = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<N-1;i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j<N;j++){
            if(abs(v[i]-v[j]) == j-i)
                obj++;
        }
    }
    data = make_pair(v,obj);
}

int check_move(int pos1, int pos2){
    int dif = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<N;i++){
        if(i == pos1 || i == pos2)
            continue;
        if(abs(data.first[i] - data.first[pos1]) == abs(i-pos1))
            dif++;
        if(abs(data.first[i] - data.first[pos2]) == abs(i-pos2))
            dif++;
        if(abs(data.first[i] - data.first[pos1]) == abs(i-pos2))
            dif--;
        if(abs(data.first[i] - data.first[pos2]) == abs(i-pos1))
            dif--;
    }
    return dif;
}

void process(){
    double T = 1.0;
    cout << "Initial Heuristic: " << data.second << endl;
    while(1){
        step++;
        if(data.second == 0)
            break;
        cout << data.second << endl;
        int pos1 = abs(rand()%N);
        int pos2 = abs(rand()%N);
        T *= 0.99;
        if (pos1 == pos2)
            continue;
        int dif = check_move(pos1, pos2);
        if(dif > 0){
            data.second -= dif;
            swap(data.first[pos1],data.first[pos2]);
            continue;
        }
        if(exp(dif/T) < abs(rand()/INT_MAX)){
            
            data.second -= dif;
            swap(data.first[pos1], data.first[pos2]);
        }
    }
}

int main(){
    clock_t start = clock();
    init();
    process();
    for (auto &&i : data.first)
    {
        cout << i << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Steps: " << step << endl;
    cout << "Time: " << clock() - start << endl;

    int conflicts = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<N-1;i++){
        for(int j=i+1;j<N;j++){
            if(abs(data.first[i]-data.first[j]) == j-i)
                conflicts++;
        }
    }
    cout << "Conflicts = " << conflicts;
}
```

Comment: whats the question? Same complexity `!=` similar runtime. You can easily write a `O(N)` algorithm that takes a year to finsish while a `O(N^2)` may take a second for the same job

Comment: What does perf say about the time usage distribution in each program?

Comment: sorry for my bad English but the thing I wonder is the reason why the first program perform so much better than the second one (although the ) because I have a requirement to completely display the 1000x1000 chessboard within 30s

Comment: I found an answer that Same complexity != similar runtime.

Comment: complexity is about asymptotic behavior. To understand difference in runtime for a given problem size, complexity is largely irrelevant. The first version is making some unnecessary copies of large vectors. I'd expect some improvement by not making those copies. FOr example, `NextMove` takes its parameter by value (ie copy) just to immediately make another copy. Even if you really need a copy, it is sufficient to copy it once. `show` makes another copy for no reason